# controller connect to directive for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I was wondering how I can combine both a directive and controller function for validating a form?

Right now I'm validating a form separately with a directive, which highlights a field purple if someone doesn't fill out the field and in my controller I repeat the same validation in order to see whether the user can proceed to saving the data.

directive.js

```
.directive('highlightOnError', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.$on('submit', function() {

        var border = '';
        if (ngModel.$invalid){
          border = 'magenta solid 1px';
          element.css('border', border);
        }  else
        {
          border="";
          element.css('border', border);
        }


      });
    }
  };
})
```

controller.js

```
for(var i=0; i<formobject.length;i++){
  var key=formobject[i];
  var field =validation.formobject[key]; 
  if(validation.formobject.hasOwnProperty(formobject[i])){
     if(field==null){
      error_count++;
      break;   
    }
}
else{
 error_count++;
 break; 
}
}
if(error_count==0){
  //save data of form
      $scope.create();
}

else{
  alert('Please fill out highlighted fields');
}
```

thanks

Comment: Either look into $broadcast/$on, or bind a scope variable into your directive.

Comment: Do you have an example? Thanks

Comment: Yup, but I don't want to deprive you of the search ;). Lol. There are lots of examples of both all over stack overflow. Try googling 'share data between directive and controller' or 'angularjs $broadcast'. Or something else.

Comment: Are you just trying to validate the entire form? The form is in a clean state if all the inputs validate. Are you sure you really need to be doing it the way you are currently? The section in the docs about forms is pretty good, especially the validation parts.

Comment: @aet I simplified the question but in reality I need to do my own custom validation i.e. phone number formats in XXX-XXX-XXXX. So its not just checking for null values otherwise yes I would ngModel.$invalid to check for null values in form

Comment: You could write directives, or a single one, that used an object format to describe your validation, like with a regex and a fail-message, and just let your directive mark each input appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Though this does not directly answer your question, it is an alternative approach that might benefit you. First create a service to hold your validations.

```
myApp.factory('ValidationService', [ '$log',
function($log) {

var validators = {
    passcode: {
        patterns: [
            {
                regex: /^[0-9]{8}$/,
                msg: "Please enter a valid 8 digit code."
            }
        ]   
    },
    password: {
        patterns: [
            {
                regex: /^.{8}.*$/,
                msg: "Please use at least 8 characters."
            },
            {
                regex: /((?=.*[a-z].*)(?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*))|((?=.*[a-z].*)(?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9].*))|((?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9].*))|((?=.*[a-z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9].*))/,
                msg: "Please use characters from 3 different categories."
            }
        ]
    },
    email: {
        patterns: [
            {
                regex: /^[^@]+@[^.]+[.][^.][^.]+.*$/,
                msg: "Please enter a valid email address."
            }
        ]
    },
    default: {
        patterns: [
            {
                regex: /^.*$/,
                msg: "Invalid validator specified. Check your html."
            }
        ]
    }
};

return {
    getValidator: getValidator
};

function getValidator(inputType) {
    if (validators[inputType]) {
        return validators[inputType];
    }
    return validators.default;
}

}]);
```

Then, a directive to work with this service:

```
myApp.directive('inputValidator', [ '$log', 'ValidationService',
function($log, ValidationService) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
            if (typeof viewValue == 'undefined') {
                return viewValue;
            }
            var pass = true;
            var validator = ValidationService.getValidator(attrs.inputValidator);
            $.each(validator.patterns, function(index, pattern) {
                if (!pattern.regex.test(viewValue)) {
                    pass = false;
                    scope[attrs.inputValidatorMsg] = pattern.msg;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if (pass) {
                // valid
                ctrl.$setValidity('inputValidator', true);
                return viewValue;
            } else {
                // invalid
                ctrl.$setValidity('inputValidator', false);
                return undefined;
            }
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

And finally, some html to tie it all together:

```
<form name="loginForm" class="css-form" data-novalidate>
            <p class="reset-header">Activate Your Account</p>

            <input type=text placeholder="Email Address" name="username" data-ng-model="username"
                    data-input-validator="email" data-input-validator-msg="usernameError" data-required>
            <span class="tag tag-alert arrow-top" data-ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.inputValidator">{{usernameError}}</span>

            <input type=text placeholder="Activation Code" name="passcode" data-ng-model="passcode"
                    data-input-validator="passcode" data-input-validator-msg="passcodeError" data-required>
            <span class="tag tag-alert arrow-top" data-ng-show="loginForm.passcode.$error.inputValidator">{{passcodeError}}</span>

            <input type=password placeholder="New Password" name="password" data-ng-model="password"
                    data-input-validator="password" data-input-validator-msg="passwordError" data-input-must-not-match="username" data-required>
            <span class="tag tag-alert arrow-top" data-ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.inputValidator">{{passwordError}}</span>
            <span class="tag tag-alert arrow-top" data-ng-show="!loginForm.password.$error.inputValidator && loginForm.password.$error.inputMustNotMatch">Please enter a password that is not your email address.</span>

            <input type=password placeholder="New Password Again" name="passwordConfirm" data-ng-model="passwordConfirm"
                    data-input-must-match="password" data-required>
            <span class="tag tag-alert arrow-top" data-ng-show="loginForm.passwordConfirm.$error.inputMustMatch">Please enter the same new password again.</span>

            <button class="btn btn-special" data-ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" data-ng-click="save()">Activate</button>
        </form>
```