# AngularJs form validation - manage custom errors priority to show only one error with the ng-show directives

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-show

here is my first question on this awesome forum.

my need is to warn the user why the number he enters is invalid, but I want to print only one message at each time. I've implemented a solution but it's not really easily evolutive.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<input type="number" name="amountReceived" class="styled" data-ng-model="cashAmountReceived" required>
<div class="error" data-ng-show="cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$error.required && cashPaymentForm.submitted">Valid amount required</div>
<div class="error" data-ng-show="cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$error.notEnought && cashPaymentForm.submitted">It's not enought</div>
<div class="error" data-ng-show="cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$error.negatif && cashPaymentForm.submitted">Positive value only</div>
```

and here is my Controller code :

```
$scope.$watch('cashAmountReceived', function() {

    if(angular.isNumber($scope.cashAmountReceived)){


         var tmp =  $scope.cashAmountReceived.toString();
         tmp = tmp.replace(/(\d{0,9})+\.(\d{0,2}).*/,'$1.$2');
         $scope.cashAmountReceived = parseFloat(tmp);

         if( $scope.cashAmountReceived < 0){
             $scope.cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$setValidity('negatif', false);
             $scope.cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$setValidity('notEnought', true);
         }
         else{
             $scope.cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$setValidity('negatif', true);

             if($scope.cashAmountReceived < $scope.totalProductPrice){
                 $scope.cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$setValidity('notEnought', false);
             }
             else{
                 $scope.cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$setValidity('notEnought', true);
             }
         }
     } 
     else{
         $scope.cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$setValidity('notEnought', true);
         $scope.cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$setValidity('negatif', true);
     }
});
```

I've to manually manage validity errors to make sure that only one will be printed thanks to the `ng-show` directives in my HTML page. I'd like to implement a easily evolutive solution, in case I need to add more validation criteria.

I think about to make my own directive with a priority management system on my custom errors and compatible with the defaults errors possibilities, but I don't know how to proceed.

Or maybe I can leave the process in the controller and create only one custom error called `custom` and define a scope variable called `errorReason` whitch will contain the appropriate warning message

I'll have something like that in my HTML code :

```
<input type="number" name="amountReceived" class="styled" data-ng-model="cashAmountReceived" required>
<div class="error" data-ng-show="cashPaymentForm.amountReceived.$error.custom && cashPaymentForm.submitted">{{errorReason}}</div>
```

What do you guys think about it?

I apologize if my english is not correct.

Comment: In the answer I gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493774/controller-connect-to-directive-for-validation/22494139#22494139 you will find a validation directive that does what you are talking about, that is, a custom error message per validation to be displayed in order of validation failure. Maybe you can use this as a starting point for what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML form validation using json schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119976/html-form-validation-using-json-schema)